# SF Action within Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, quickaction

Is there a way to input a standard sales force quick action (specifically email) inside of a custom component?

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question on the lightning now forum and received this response:

Vin Addala (Salesforce)
It is currently not possible to call quick actions from your custom components. It is on the roadmap. Safe harbor. We are definitely looking at ways on how to make this possible in the future with lightning components.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a long way:

Take a look at using restapi from Lightning:

http://peterknolle.com/rest-api-lightning-component/

in your child component use

path = /services/data/v40.0/actions/standard/emailSimple

Note: Userinfo.getsessionId() was not working as described in the post. I had to define a connected app get the "Access_token" and use it my authorization string to execute the email action.

If you have trouble let me know, I will post the complete code